# How to download files from google cloud storage to user pc (React)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I have files on google cloud storage and i want to add a button so that users can download those files to their pc. I tried the usual:

```
<a href="imageUrlHere" download="testImage">Download</a>
```

But it only opens the image file in the same tab.

Everything running on the front end of the app by the way.

Comment: Firestore doesn't store files.  It's a NoSQL document-oriented database.  Did you mean Cloud Storage instead?

Comment: yes, sorry i will fix it

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the download URL of the File stored in Cloud Storage, the following function will do the trick:

```
triggerBrowserDownload(url) {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
  link.setAttribute('target', 'new');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
}
```

And you can call it with

```
<a onclick=triggerBrowserDownload("imageUrlHere")>Download</a>
```

---

Or, better, by adding a listener:

**HTML**

```
<a id="urlLink" url="imageUrlHere">Try it</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("urlLink").addEventListener('click', triggerBrowserDownload);

triggerBrowserDownload(evt) {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = evt.target.attributes.value.url;
  link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
  link.setAttribute('target', 'new');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
}
```

Comment: This only opens the file in a new tab, maybe because I'm using react? I don't know anymore, i have tried so many things, thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using HTML attributes would be to set the `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment; filename="file.ext"` so you can use the `downloadURL` so whenever the URL is opened in new tab, it'll be downloaded. This can be set in the metadata when uploading the file or you can use `updateMetadata()` function to add it for existing files.

```
const storageRef = ref(storage, 'image.png')

// Adding metadata while uploading files
await uploadBytes(
  storageRef,
  file,
  {
    contentDisposition: `attachment; filename="${file.name}"`,
  }
)

// Updating metadata for existing files
await updateMetadata(storageRef, {
  contentDisposition: 'attachment; filename="image.png"',
})
```

You just need to redirect the user to a new tab. If you don't specify the `filename`, the browser will prompt user to enter one.

```
<a href="URL_FROM_FIREBASE" target="_blank">Download</a>
```